# Create the global variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried to get the value of the id of my list using this code :

```
var ticket = '';
$(".selectedcategory").mouseover(function () {
   ticket = this.id;
});
$("#subCat").remove();
var urlCat = '<%: Url.Content("~/") %>' + "Gallery/TestGallery";
var list = $(".level1").append('<ul ></ul>').find('ul');

$.getJSON(urlCat, { Depid: ticket }, function (dataCat) {
  $.each(dataCat, function (indexCat, dataOptionCat) {
      list.append('<li><a href="teste">' + dataOptionCat.Name + '</a></li>');
});
});
```

I want to get the id of the ".selectedcategory" is "ticket" to use in "`$.getJSON(urlCat, { Depid: ticket }, function (dataCat) {`"  , but it is undefined when using outside the `mouseover()` function.

Could anyone tell me how to get this.id outside the `mouseover()` function please?

Thanks so much.

Comment: The reason it is undefined (or, technically, `""`) is because `$.getJSON` is executing immediately after the `<script />` is loaded, where-as `ticket` is populated once the `.selectedcategory` has been `mouseover`'d. What behaviour are you expecting to happen?

Comment: your getJSON is called before your mouse is over!

Comment: So any suggestion to avoid this please??

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at the time getJSON is called, the mouseover function has not been called yet, thus ticket remains undefined.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but since the result of getJSON seems to depend on the ticket, you could call getJSON inside your mouseover function as well.

Comment: I used to try to put the JSON inside the mouseover() function too, But the <li> that I have appended, will increase more and more whenever I hover the <li>. So I don't know how to avoid it. Could you give me any suggestion?

Comment: @titi: Then you have at least two issues. One is with the `ticket` variable not being assigned a value you want, the second one is with what would happen next (if the correct value is assigned). There is some work to be done ;)

Comment: Sorry , I couldn't understand what you mean Tadeck.

Comment: if you only want it to happen once, you could unbind the mouseover event inside the mouseover function.

Answer (score 1):

### What is the problem

By the following code:

```
$(".selectedcategory").mouseover(function () {
   ticket = this.id;
});
```

you do not immediately execute `ticket = this.id` assignement, **you only attach event handler** for `mouseover` to the category. Later in the code you are pulling JSON passing empty string within the request params.

### How you can solve this and similar problems in your code

Just use event-based programming, by invoking functions only when specific event occurs, and possibly passing callbacks to them. You could learn it by searching the web - one of the resources is here: http://mostlygeek.com/tech/event-driven-programming-with-jquery/ (it is based on the older jQuery, though, so replace `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.delegate()` with proper usage of `.on()` from the newest jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I just a beginner developer so I have no idea much about it. I will try to read it step by step :)